# Elegant way to toggle/flip/alternate between to functions (C)

Tags: c, arduino

Is there a more elegant way to do something like this:

```
if(millis() - time >= 100) {
   time = millis();
   if(toggle == 1){
      dothis();
      toggle = 0;
   }
   else {
      dothat();
      toggle = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: That probably depends on your definition of "elegant" and what problem you have with the current version. There's always alternative solutions, but the question is whether there's any benefit to using them over the "simple" ones

Comment: What is "something like this" exactly? Does the provided example even mirrors your idea/the intended purpose? Why would you want to toggle a value in a variable in just an `if` statement (I mean the outer `if`)? Has `toggle` any purpose thereafter or is this part of a loop? What is the idea in whole?

Comment: I think your current way is the most elegant and best readable way. Except for the unnecessary call of `milis()`. You can change it to `if((tmp=millis())-time>=100) {time= tmp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close to a matter of taste. IMHO the common way for toggling is `toggle = 1 - toggle;`.

And if performance matters, dereferencing is normally more efficient than a test, so you could build a array of (pointers to) functions:

```
typedef void (*dofunc)(void);
dofunc func[] = {&dothat, &dothis};
...
int toggle = 0;
...
if((t = millis()) - time >= 100) {
    time = t;
    func[toggle]();
    toggle = 1 - toggle;
}
```

Comment: or shorter `fun[toggle ^⁼ 1]();` (I was writting that in an answer, I cancel, too close to your). Better to put *func* const, and why not  static ?

Comment: You have an unnecessary call of `millis()` and in between the result could have changed. Not elegant.

Comment: Oh... I see he has too. See my comment to improve that part.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I focused on the `toggle` part, but you are right. Post edited

Comment: Still open what the purpose of the `toggle` this. Is this meant to run in a loop? OP should clarify what s/he wants to achieve which reasons the toggle so that one can give a "elegant" solution for the whole problem.

Comment: "*Close to a matter of taste*" - Exactly. Although I guess OP really meant "simple" or "sneaky" instead of "elegant".

Comment: dofunc func[] = {&dothat, &dothis}; <<- this! very nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
// if the condition is OK, then continue
if(!(millis() - time >= 100))
    return; // exit from the function

// common to both if and else cases
time = millis();

// toggles and does the first case if it was false,
// otherwise another case when it was true
(toggle ^= 1) ? dothat() : dothis();
```

Another way to toggle the `toggle`:

```
toggle = !toggle;
```

Supposing the `toggle` is 1, then `!toggle` will be 0 and vice versa.

Comment: Just difficult to read; not elegant

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I've just given - probably the shortest way to do what the OP wants.

Comment: There is one thing to consider: "*Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones’ complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case of sign and magnitude and ones’ complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a negative zero.*" + "*If the implementation does not support negative zeros, the behavior of the &, |, ^, ~, <<, and >> operators with operands that would produce such a value is undefined.*" --- C18, 6.2.6.2/2+4

Comment: It may be the shortest, but surely not the most elegant way, which includes readability.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie [Relink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770717/elegant-way-to-toggle-flip-alternate-between-to-functions-c#comment111003017_62770717)